# Running selenium, cucumber and Page Factory. Second step definition fail to run

Tags: selenium, cucumber, page-factory

I wrote a cucumber framework that has two feature files and two stepdefinitions which are glued to the feature files. When i run the test together, it ran for the first stepDefinition and fail to enter the second stepDefinition. I have initialize my pages and yet couldn't get it to work.

Error and Codes below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.click(Unknown Source)
    at Pages.HomePage.CreateANewOrderPage.createOrderLink(CreateANewOrderPage.java:35)
    at StepDefinitions.CreateOrderStep.user_click_on_create_a_new_order(CreateOrderStep.java:24)
    at ✽.When user click on create a new order(CreateOrder.feature:5)


 public class CreateANewOrderPage  {
           WebDriver driver;
     public CreateANewOrdePage(WebDriver driver){
            this.driver=driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

        @FindBy (linkText= "Create a new order")
        public WebElement createOrderLink;

     public void createOrderLink(){
            createOrderLink.click();
        }

public class SigninPage {

    WebDriver driver;
        public SigninPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"userName\"]")
    public WebElement usernameField;

    @FindBy(name="password")
    public WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(id="buttonSubmitLogin")
    public WebElement submitBtn;

 public void loginDetails(String uname, String psw) {

        usernameField.sendKeys(uname);
        passwordField.sendKeys(psw);}

        public void clickLogin(){
            submitBtn.click();
        }  
}


 public class SigninStep {
         WebDriver driver;

        SigninPage logIn = new SigninPage(driver);    

        @Given("^user navigates to mySite$")
        public void userNavigatesToMysite() throws Throwable {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\mypc\\Documents\\Automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("www.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

            @And("^user enter \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
        public void userEnterValidCredentials(String validuname, String validpsw) throws Throwable {
            SigninPage logIn = new SigninPage(driver);
            logIn.loginDetails("jdjdjdj","jjdjdj");

        }
     @When("^user click on Sign in$")
        public void userClickSignIn() throws Throwable {
           SigninPage logIn = new SigninPage(driver);
           logIn.clickLogin();
                }
    }


public class CreateOrderStep  {

       WebDriver driver;

        CreateANewOrderPage ordercreate;

        @When("^user click on create a new order$")
        public void user_click_on_create_a_new_order() throws Throwable {
    ordercreate= PageFactory.initElements(driver,CreateANewOrderPage.class);
            ordercreate.createOrderLink();

        }

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions (features = "src\\test\\java\\Features\\",
                       glue ={"StepDefinitions"},
                       tags={"@Signin, @CreateOrder"}
                       //format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination.."}
           // format={"json:target/Destination/cucumber.json"
    )

    public class SigninRunner {

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: without any code added, only think that needs to be checked is that the existing driver instance is not being passed to the second pageobject.

Comment: @Grasshopper i have added the codes. Thanks

Comment: can someone please help with this? Thanks

Comment: @Grasshopper can you please help with this. Thanks

Comment: How is the driver initialized in the CreateOrderStep  class? As per the code added it is not being initialized.

Comment: When i initialised the browser in CreateOrderStep, I was getting two browsers open and still not running the test for the second browser.

Comment: You need to pass the driver instance into this class else u will get the NPE

Comment: I have done that and it opens up a second blank browser. Thanks